# Corretta interpretazione della frase "il processo avviene in modo totalmente trasparente all'utente"

Tags: meaning

Oggi al lavoro è sorto un dilemma non da poco circa la frase:

> Il processo avviene in modo totalmente trasparente all'utente.

Ci siamo resi conto che circa metà delle persone presenti (me compresa) interpretava questa frase come

> L'utente rimane totalmente ignaro che stia succedendo qualcosa

mentre l'altra metà di noi la interpretava come

> L'utente è pienamente consapevole e viene avvisato del processo che si sta svolgendo

Qualcuno sa fornirmi qualche riferimento che indichi quale interpretazione della frase è quella corretta?

Comment: In informatica, se una cosa (p.es. un processo) è trasparente significa che (normalmente) è "invisibile". Non posso escludere però che in un altro ambito (burocratico, politico, ministeriale...) il significato sia l'altro riportato. Qual è l'ambito in questo caso?

Comment: Che il processo sia totalmente trasparente _allo_ utente e non totalmente trasparente _per_ l'utente rinforza a mio parere la prima interpretazione.

Comment: @WalterTross l'ambito è informatico, ma le persone che si confrontano non sono tutte dei tecnici. Mi piacerebbe avere qualche riferimento proprio per rendere più chiara la comunicazione lavorativa!

Comment: Da informatico confermo l'interpretazione di Walter. Se si vuole disambiguare si può dire *il processo è completamente invisibile all'utente* o, al contrario, *il processo è completamente visibile all'utente* o qualcosa come *il processo notifica l'utente di ogni elaborazione avvenuta* se si vuole dare un significato più procedurale alla descrizione.

Comment: Personalmente, di primo acchito penserei alla prima interpretazione, ma poi mi verrebbe il dubbio, anche perché lo steso problema si verifica nel linguaggio politico-giornalistico. Credo a partire dalla glasnost' (resa appunto spesso infedelmente con “trasparenza”) di Gorbačëv, si parla impropriamente di procedimenti trasparenti, o amministrazione trasparente etc. quando invece si intende dire che è tutto fatto alla luce del sole e si vede benissimo.

Comment: Quale che sia l'interpretazione, occorre dire '*trasparente per l'utente*', non '*trasparente all'utente*'.

Comment: In catalano e in spagnolo abbiamo esattamente lo stesso problema. Da alcuni anni, soprattutto nell'ambito politico, c'è la moda di usare i vocaboli "trasparente" e "trasparenza" per indicare qualcosa che si fa senza nascondere niente alla gente. Penso, però, che l'uso proprio dell'aggettivo "trasparente" provenga dalla fisica: un materiale trasparente è quello che permette alla radiazione di passare attraverso senza assorbimento. Cioè, la radiazione è in certo senso "ignara" alla presenza di questo materiale. Dunque la interpretazione corretta sarebbe la prima.

Comment: Un altro esempio tratto dalla fisica: noi siamo trasparenti ai neutrini. Cioè i neutrini vi attraversano senza interagire con la materia.

Comment: Pensandoci meglio, non credo che la frase possa in nessun caso significare "l'utente è pienamente consapevole e viene avvisato del processo che si sta svolgendo". Per analogia a "il vetro è trasparente", cioè "il vetro non nasconde quello che c'è dietro", l'aggettivo "trasparente" si può usare in senso figurato per indicare qualcosa che si fa senza voler nascondere niente alla gente. Ma questo non significa che la gente sia necessariamente consapevole di tutti i dettagli di tale fatto.

Comment: Credo che nell'ambito informatico "un processo trasparente per l'utente" possa significare un processo basato completamente su software libero. Penso che forse sia la preposizione usata e anche il contesto a disambiguare tra l'uno e l'altro significato. Che ne pensate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se il processo è trasparente all'utente significa che egli può essere totalmente ignaro di ciò che accade o comunque non c'è bisogno che faccia qualcosa.

Ad esempio, se un utente invia una mail, egli non sa che essa deve passare per vari server, essere tradotta in codice binario e cose così. La cosa si rifà al discorso del back-end.

È altrettanto vero che però, in politica o cose simili, se c'è trasparenza, vuol dire che le cose si fanno in modo chiaro ed il cittadino può capire ciò di cui si parla. In questo caso, comunque, la parola "utente" fa capire che non siamo in questo campo.

Come scrive DaG:

«in politica o cose simili, se c'è trasparenza, vuol dire che...»: Infatti, in quegli ambiti “trasparenza” è usato in modo erroneo. Se una pratica burocratica, o l'iter con cui si arriva ad approvare una legge sono “trasparenti”, vorrebbe dire che non li si vede, che è l'esatto contrario di quello che dovrebbe accadere in una nazione democratica, e in ogni modo l'esatto contrario di quello che intende chi usa questa parola così.

Comment: Nonostante sia informatico, non capisco l'ultima frase.

Comment: Front-end é ciò con cui l'utente viene a confronto, ad esempio la GUI, il back-end é ciò che ci sta dietro

Comment: «in politica o cose simili, se c'è trasparenza, vuol dire che...»: Infatti, in quegli ambiti “trasparenza” è usato in modo erroneo. Se una pratica burocratica, o l'iter con cui si arriva ad approvare una legge sono “trasparenti”, vorrebbe dire che non li si vede, che è l'esatto contrario di quello che dovrebbe accadere in una nazione democratica, e in ogni modo l'esatto contrario di quello che intende chi usa questa parola così.

Comment: Esatto, ora lo aggiungo alla risposta.

Comment: @DaG: Non sono sicura che tale uso sia sempre erroneo. Per analogia a "il vetro è trasparente", cioè "il vetro non nasconde quello che c'è dietro", penso che l'aggettivo "trasparente" possa usarsi in senso figurato per indicare qualcosa che si fa senza voler nascondere niente alla gente. Ad esempio: "Il referendum si è svolto in modo trasparente".

Comment: @Charo: Giusto, ma se il vetro è trasparente, lui stesso non si vede. E se il modo in cui si tenuto un referendum è trasparente, vorrebbe dire che è il modo a non vedersi, quando invece si intende che tutto (comprese le modalità di svolgimento) è avvenuto alla luce del sole. Quindi sarebbe meglio dire che il modo (o le procedure di un appalto, o l'iter di una legge o quel che è) è palese, visibile etc.

Comment: @DaG: Si potrebbe anche interpretare come "il modo in cui si è tenuto il referendum non nasconde quello che c'è dietro".

Comment: @DaG: Dal [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/trasparente/). ***Trasparente***  In senso figurato: Anche di atti, comportamenti, situazioni, procedimenti in cui tutto è chiaro, aperto, palese, facilmente verificabile e controllabile (cfr. trasparenza, n. 2 b).

Comment: @DaG: Si può anche dire "una maglietta trasparente". La maglietta non è invisibile, ma fatta di un tessuto tanto sottile da non nascondere quello che c'è dietro.

Comment: Un discorso politico è *trasparente* quando non nasconde le intenzioni. Non è tanto diverso dal senso informatico: il discorso serve a mediare tra l'oratore e chi ascolta, esattamente come i vari processi mediano tra chi spedisce e chi riceve un'email.